# Configure Auth for multi-site project in laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, laravel-5

I'm building a multi-site project under Laravel 5, everything is working fine, routes are splitted by groups, views and controllers are within the routes, but something that i don't get how to do is work with auth in both projects, this is the structure so far:

```
app    
|---Http
|    |---Controllers
|        |----------Club
|        |          |---IndexCtrl
|        |          |---ClientsCtrl
|        |          |--- ...
|        | 
|        |----------Center
|        |          |----IndexCtrl
|        |          |----UsersCtrl
|        |          |----ServicesCtrl
|        |          |---- ...
|        |
|        |----------Auth
|
|---- ...
|
|----resources
     |-------- ...
     |--------views
              |----Auth
              |----Center
              |----Club
              |---- ...
```

The two sites are Club, and Center, at Club there are Clients who can login to the clients area, at Center there are users who can login to the website administration.

Right now i can login to Center because Auth has the default configurations, and i'm using Laravel 5 default user management, but i would like to have another auth for clients(That means another login form, but same table for users in db).

**UPDATE 1:**
Here's my routes.php

```
Route::group(array('domain' => 'site.center', 'namespace' => 'Center', 'middleware' => 'auth',), function () {

    Route::get('/', [
        'as' => 'adminIndex',
        'uses' => 'AdminCtrl@index'
    ]);

    Route::get('/out', [
        'as' => 'adminOut',
        'uses' => 'AdminCtrl@out'
    ]);
});

Route::group(array('domain' => 'site.club', 'namespace' => 'Club', 'middleware' => 'auth',), function () {

    Route::get('/', [
        'as' => 'publicIndex',
        'uses' => 'PublicCtrl@index'
    ]);

    Route::get('/out', [
        'as' => 'publicOut',
        'uses' => 'PublicCtrl@out'
    ]);
});

//Routes for auth
Route::controllers([
    'auth' => 'Auth\AuthController',
    'password' => 'Auth\PasswordController',
]);

Route::get('/register', [
    'as' => 'register',
    'uses' => 'Auth\AuthController@getRegister'
]);

Route::post('/register', [
    'as' => 'post.register',
    'uses' => 'Auth\AuthController@postRegister'
]);

Route::get('/in', [
    'as' => 'in',
    'uses' => 'Auth\AuthController@getLogin'
]);

Route::post('/in', [
    'as' => 'post.in',
    'uses' => 'Auth\AuthController@postLogin'
]);

Route::get('/out', [
    'as' => 'out',
    'uses' => 'Auth\AuthController@getLogout'
]);
```

How could i have different views of login and register for Club and Center ?

Comment: And what does it mean "I would like to have another auth for clients"? Separate login form? Separate user table? Something else?

Comment: Already clarified @jedrzej.kurylo

Comment: Do you have any area that requires being logged in but is available to both types of users?

Comment: No, there are sections in the club site where the client must be logged in, and all the section in Center require a logged in user, none of the Club and Clients area are related by a single login @jedrzej.kurylo

Comment: So why do you want to make it a single application? Making that work will require some additional work that you wouldn't need to do if you just had 2 applications.

Comment: The problem is that Laravel's auth stores user ID in session and uses it to load user for every request. With separate tables you'll have the same IDs in different tables so the default behaviour won't work. Getting that to work, if IDs might be the same in different tables, will be difficulty - you'll probably need to provide your own Auth class implementation as overwriting user provider won't be enough.

Comment: Well, I decide to make the two applications in a single one to share storage folder, also to share models; with the ID thing, if I would store them in a single table would it be easier? ¡f so, how could I handle user type? By now I use Entrust, with Roles and permissions, I guess it could be done by adding a role for clients, but I need it to be different login views @jedrzej.kurylo

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/85142/discussion-between-jedrzej-kurylo-and-jonthan-solorzano).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Notice:** as turned out in comments, what is needed is a possibility to have 2 login form, each allowing authenticating only specific type of user. Storing users in a single database with **type** column is acceptable.

The above logic can still be achieved using Laravel's authentication logic wrapped in **AuthenticatesUsers** trait. It's all described in the docs here http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/authentication#authenticating-users so I'll just describe what needs to be changed to get what you need.

In order to achieve that, you need to do following (this is one of the options):

1. Add **type** field to your **users** table - I'll assume that you have 2 types: **user** and **client**
2. Create 2 actions that display login forms - I'm not going to paste the code, it's just a simple action that displays a form, I'm sure you can handle that :) The form should ask for **username/email** (or whatever field you use to authethicate users) and password.
3. Create 2 controllers that those forms will submit to:

   ```
   class UserAuthController extends Controller {
     use AuthenticatesUsers;

     // field used for authentication 
     protected $username = 'username'; //or email or whatever you need      

     // get credentials from request that will be used for authentication
     protected function getCredentials(Request $request)
     {
       return array_merge($request->only($this->loginUsername(), 'password'), ['type' => 'user']);
     }
   }

   class ClientAuthController extends Controller {
     use AuthenticatesUsers;

     // field used for authentication 
     protected $username = 'username'; //or email or whatever you need      

     // get credentials from request that will be used for authentication
     protected function getCredentials(Request $request)
     {
       return array_merge($request->only($this->loginUsername(), 'password'), ['type' => 'client']);
     }
   }
   ```

And that's it. The most important part is adding **type** field to credentials. Laravel's logic that gets executed when user logs in will now not only try to match username and password, but also type. So if someone provides client credentials but type is set to **user** they won't authenticate.

**Update:** As pointed out in the comments, some changes to **auth** and **guest** middleware might be needed to redirect to proper routes depending on user type.

**guest** middleware redirects authenticated users to their homepage if they try to access page that should be available for unauthentic users only, like **login form**. With 2 areas for **users** and **clients**, user type needs to be considered to redirect to corresponding homepage. The middleware's **RedirectIfAuthenticated::handle()** method needs to be updated:

```
if ($this->auth->check()) {
  return redirect('/home');
}
```

needs to become

```
if ($this->auth->check()) {
  // update with whatever routes you consider **home** for both types
  return redirect($this->auth->user()->type == 'user' ? '/userhome' : '/clienthome');
}
```

The **auth** middleware on the other hand redirects unauthenticated users to login form when they try to access restricted area. As with above code you'll have separate login forms for 2 types of users, a proper redirect needs to be done depending on the area user tries to access. The **Authenticate::handle()** method needs to be updated:

```
return redirect()->guest('auth/login');
```

needs to become

```
return redirect()->guest($request->route()->domain() == 'site.center' ? 'userauth' : 'clientauth');
```

Comment: Got it, so that each group of routes will have that controller? i mean, if you checked out the routes configuration, Club and Center are grouped, and outside of them there are the custom routes for login, register, and logout. Laravel 5 default auth has a folder and inside it there are two controllers: AuthController and PasswordController, will i use them, or this will do the trick ?

Comment: @jedrzej.kurylo This covers login, but you will also need to change the `auth` and `guest` middlewear to account for the **type** right?

Comment: @Jeemusu: it depends. The default implementation of "guest" middleware redirects to /home. If it's ok for both types, then no changes needed. If not, then a simple if will suffice: "return redirect($this->auth->user->type == 'user' ? '/userhome' : '/clienthome');

Comment: @jedrzej.kurylo I thought the base Laravel 5.1 app includes `auth`, `guest`, `auth.basic` [middleware](http://laravel.com/docs/master/middleware#registering-middleware) ?

Comment: Yes, just noticed that in the code :) "auth" middleware redirects unauthenticated users to login form. You could need some addditional logic in there to identify which area user wants to access and redirect to correct login form. I'll update the answer in a moment with an example

Comment: @JonathanS.I understood you need separete login form for different user types. If so, you'll need 2 login routes to 2 login forms and 2 controllers - you can reuse the AuthController from Laravel. If you only need one form and want to just redirect user to correct area dependiing on their role, that's also possible - let me know if that's the case and I'll update the answer

Comment: Yes, what i need is two different login forms, but configured for each route group.

Comment: Does the trait `AuthenticatesUsers ` exists or is `AuthenticatesAndRegistersUsers` ?

Comment: In Laravel 5.0 you only had AuthenticatesAndRegistersUsers. Laravel 5.1 added AuthenticatesUsers and RegistersUsers traits.

Comment: May i open a chat, i need to clarify somethings

Comment: Check out the chat from the comments in the main post